# ionic 3 Keyboard events, keycode always 0

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, keyboard-events, keycode

I am trying to control what a user can type to a specific input in my ionic 3 app.
For example i have an `input type='text'` that i am allowing only numbers and underscores to it, and i am trying to achieve this using keyboard event.

This works on browsers but not on actual android, since all keyCode are 0;

Please advice how to deal with such thing, and am i using the best approach?

Html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="pinForm">
  <div class="modal-input">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pin" #pinNumber></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</form>
```

ts Code:

```
@ViewChild('pinNumber') inputPin:any;
@HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
     //here i am controlling the input to do what ever i need
     console.log(e);
  }
```

the code above works in browser on pc but not on actual device
as shown below its all 0's

so how to know what key is pressed?

> altGraphKey: false
>
> altKey: false
>
> bubbles: true
>
> cancelBubble: false
>
> cancelable: true
>
> charCode: 0
>
> clipboardData: undefined
>
> ctrlKey: false
>
> currentTarget: null
>
> defaultPrevented: true
>
> detail: 0
>
> eventPhase: 0
>
> keyCode: 0
>
> keyIdentifier: "U+0000"
>
> keyLocation: 0
>
> layerX: 0
>
> layerY: 0
>
> location: 0
>
> metaKey: false
>
> pageX: 0
>
> pageY: 0
>
> returnValue: false
>
> shiftKey: false
>
> srcElement: input.text-input text-input-md
>
> target: input.text-input text-input-md
>
> timeStamp: 1516972480017
>
> type:"keydown"
>
> view: Window
>
> which: 0
>
> **proto**: KeyboardEvent

Comment: Try this `@HostListener('document:keydown, ['$event'])`

Comment: @santoshsingh still the same.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: @PhilipBrack i tested on samnsung s8  and  samsung grand 2 android 4.4.2

Comment: also tried `(keyup)="eventHandler($event)"`

```eventHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
}```
still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `type="tel"` since on old androids `type="text"`, for some reason, reset the keyboard event variables. so after using `type="tel"` the keycode was logged successfully for all characters except for the backspace,

i used `(ngModelChange)` to track changes and then i checked if its backspace and then i handled as per my requirements, but the logic was to check the the size of the input and act accordingly.

> please note that i needed to do this since i need a different behavior for backspace, if you don't do anything the default behavior is the normal one.

Comment: I tried to log this on an android device but it gives me always 229. Is there a possible way to get the **next** button keycode on a real device?